# background image not showing in div

Tags: html, css

I am not able to have a background image show in a div.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/a2hVV/1/).  Can someone show me where I am going wrong please?  This seems like a simple thing to do.

Answer (score 8):

You simply need a height for the div if you wish to see it.

Divs automatically have 100% width and 0 height.

[See what happens when you add height.](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/a2hVV/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Your `div` is empty. Put some text in it, and the background image will appear.

Alternatively, give your `div` a height.

Answer (score 2):

Add `height:32px;` and `width:32px;` to show one arrow ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2hVV/4/)). The height of a `div` is determined by its content, so if you want to render the background of a container either specify its height or fill it with content.